# Which of sap.ui.require or sap.ui.define should I use?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, amd

As far as I understand, in many cases `sap.ui.require` and `sap.ui.define` are interchangeable. However, there is a [convention](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/f665d0de4dba405f9af4294de824b03b):

> - *Use `sap.ui.define` for controllers and all other JavaScript modules to define a global namespace. With the namespace, the object can be addressed throughout the application.*
> - *Use `sap.ui.require` for asynchronously loading dependencies but without declaring a namespace, for example code that just needs to be executed, but does not need to be called from other code.*

I read this statement several times, but I'm not sure I got it completely.
For instance, when I write an UI5-controller for the specific UI5-view, then what should I use? And when I write a `BaseController.js`, which the rest of the controllers will be based on, then should I chose `sap.ui.define` or `sap.ui.require`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3047#issuecomment-711078236) to the SAPUI5 team, `sap.ui.define` is similar to the static `import` and `export` statements in ES6 modules, while `sap.ui.require` is more like the dynamic `import()` statement.

Basically all UI5 module definitions (incl. view controllers' code) should start with `sap.ui.define` on the top level, while `sap.ui.require` should be used if in the middle of the code I want to import some other UI5 modules.

For more details on the subject: [Differences between `sap.ui.require` and `sap.ui.define`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/blob/3d52e2ba94aa8bfcaf009594b09ef8b7e7cfb363/docs/Troubleshooting_for_Loading_Modules_4363b3f.md#using-sapuirequire-instead-of-sapuidefine-on-the-top-level).